# Запоминаем адрес объекта в памяти, которая принадлежит окну

Tags: c++, winapi

С помощью SetWindowLong устанавливаю смещение, и помещаю туда адрес объекта своего класса.
Но, функция упорно возвращает 0. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
class Test
{
    int *a;
    std::string test;
public:
    Test(){}
    void Tests(HWND hwnd)
    {
        LONG res = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)this); // в res возвращается 0
        return;
    }
};
```

P.S.: делаю для того, чтобы из оконной процедуры можно было обратиться к классу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вообще-то, `SetWindowLong` возвращает старое значение или `0` в случае ошибки. Однако если старое значение само по себе было `0` (что всегда имеет место при первом вызове с `GWL_USERDATA`), то будет возвращен, разумеется, именно `0` и это совсем не будет означать, что произошла ошибка.

Другими словами, в случае `GWL_USERDATA` по возвращенному значению `0` еще невозможно утверждать, что что-то не в порядке. Если вы подозреваете, что произошла ошибка - проверяйте `GetLastError`. (Однако я нигде не вижу гарантии, что `SetWindowLong` ставит last error в `0` в случае успеха, поэтому для надежности в таком случае имеет смысл предварительно сделать `SetLastError(0)` самому.)

Можете также для надежности сделать `GetWindowLong`, чтобы убедиться, что значение успешно записалось.

Answer (score 3):

Функция `SetWindowLong` возвращает предыдущее значение параметра. Для `GWL_USERDATA` начальное значение равно нулю, поэтому это вполне нормально. Если вы подозреваете ошибку, нужно перед запуском сбросить код ошибки через `SetLastError` и после запуска взять его через `GetLastError`.

К слову, функция `SetWindowLong` не имеет смысла в 64-битных приложениях (поэтому лучше использовать `SetWindowLongPtr`).